# Fetch minimum effective date comparing current and previous rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Im working on Oracle 12c, I have a requirement to fetch the minimum effective date based on group by of columns, however for only period until there is no change, example below :

Assume we have Employee ID who changes departments over period of time and we want to capture the minimum effective date per department as below but minimum effective date only until the change.

| EMP_ID | EFF_DT | DEPT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 01/01/2015 | ENGINEERING |
| 100 | 01/01/2016 | ENGINEERING |
| 100 | 01/01/2017 | ENGINEERING |
| 100 | 01/01/2018 | FINANCE |
| 100 | 01/01/2019 | FINANCE |
| 100 | 01/01/2020 | ENGINEERING |
| 100 | 01/01/2021 | ENGINEERING |

Target:

| EMP_ID | EFF_DT | DEPT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 01/01/2015 | ENGINEERING |
| 100 | 01/01/2018 | FINANCE |
| 100 | 01/01/2020 | ENGINEERING |

How to accomplish ? I tried doing LAG and trying to compare current and previous but not able to identify the minimum during the timeframe of no change.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Also good to know: your Oracle database ***version*** - as different solutions are available depending on version. Run `select * from v$version` if you don't know your version.

Comment: OK, I see you edited to add your version. Even more useful is the full version - such as 12.1.0.2 or 12.2.0.1. There are significant differences between 12.1 and 12.2 (or 9.1. and 9.2, etc.) - and sometimes meaningful differences even down to the fourth part of the version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `match_recognize` (available since version 12.1 of the database)

Setting up data for testing:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy';

create table my_table (emp_id, eff_dt, dept_id) as
  select 100, to_date('01/01/2015'), 'ENGINEERING' from dual union all
  select 100, to_date('01/01/2016'), 'ENGINEERING' from dual union all
  select 100, to_date('01/01/2017'), 'ENGINEERING' from dual union all
  select 100, to_date('01/01/2018'), 'FINANCE'     from dual union all
  select 100, to_date('01/01/2019'), 'FINANCE'     from dual union all
  select 100, to_date('01/01/2020'), 'ENGINEERING' from dual union all
  select 100, to_date('01/01/2021'), 'ENGINEERING' from dual
;
```

Query and output:

```
select emp_id, eff_dt, dept_id
from   my_table
match_recognize(
  partition by emp_id
  order     by eff_dt
  all rows per match
  pattern   ( a {- b* -} )
  define    b as dept_id = a.dept_id
);

    EMP_ID EFF_DT     DEPT_ID    
---------- ---------- -----------
       100 01/01/2015 ENGINEERING
       100 01/01/2018 FINANCE    
       100 01/01/2020 ENGINEERING
```

Brief explanation:

The `match_recognize` clause partitions the input rows by `emp_id` and orders them by `eff_dt`. Then it further divides the rows, within each partition and following the date order, into "matches", matching the pattern given in the `pattern` clause. That is a single `a` row followed by 0 or more `b` rows, where `b` is defined (in the `define` clause) to require that the `dept_id` be the same as in the first row of the match. There are no conditions for a row to be an `a` row; any row, if it cannot be classified as `b`, will be classified as `a` (and it will start a new match!)

"All" rows in a match are returned, except those enclosed in `{- -}` in the `pattern` clause. That is: the `a` row (first row) in each match is returned, while the `b` rows are not. Exactly as specified.

**EDIT**

For Oracle version 11.2 or lower, and also for database products (other than Oracle) that don't yet support `match_recognize`, this can be done with analytic functions, which are supported by the vast majority of databases.

The version below does almost exactly the same things as the `match_recognize` solution:

```
select emp_id, eff_dt, dept_id
from   (
         select emp_id, eff_dt, dept_id,
                case when lag(dept_id) over (partition by emp_id
                                             order     by eff_dt) = dept_id
                     then 'B' else 'A' end as classifier
         from   my_table
       )
where  classifier = 'A'
;
```

Comment: Hi Mathguy,My version does support it so it works good, if you dont mind im curious to know how would we have done this without "MATCH_RECOGNIZE", is there much common SQL syntax which could work on most of the databases.

Comment: @okkadu - added an analytic functions solution, written so that it is almost identical to the `match_recognize` solution (even down to the classifiers `A` and `B` from the `define` clause of `match_recognize`, and the `where` clause mirroring the `{- -}` syntax in the `pattern` clause to exclude the `B` rows from the output). **Classifier** is what the aliases in the `define` clause are known as, if you were to use them in the `match_recognize` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially the lag one, I have written similar query but my mind is rusty that I never thought about filter on the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and I think the fastest way to implement this query uses `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(dept_id) over (partition by emp_id order by eff_dt) as prev_dept_id
      from t
     ) t
where prev_dept_id is null or prev_dept_id <> dept_id;
```

Comment: Why do you think this is faster than `match_recognize`? Did you ever run tests yourselves, or did you see this claimed anywhere? Everything I have seen suggests that `match_recognize` is faster, so it would be interesting to hear why you "think" that.

Comment: Also, `match_recognize` is covered in the SQL Standard - 2016, and supported by several db products (although fewer than support analytic functions).

Comment: See for example https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c065143_ISO_IEC_TR_19075-5_2016.zip (for `match_recognize` in the 2016 SQL Standard).